# Download and save a zip file from httppost response as binary data in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, zip, binary-data

Thanks in advance..

First, I'm asking this for android.

I have to send a http post request with a zip file containing an xml file having list of names in it.

now, according to the list of name I sent, the server will send me the binary data of a zip file and I have to save that binary data (response) as a zip file.

the problem is, when I'm saving this binary data as a zip file, it is not able to extract the zip then.

I think this could be some character set problem too.. that i need to convert the received binary data to some character set and then save it as a zip..

please Help me in this, I'm new to android. and any ASYNC task example for doing the same will be great Help.

This is my code..

```
private class sendMissingImagesToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        String uri = params[0];
        try {

            MultipartEntityBuilder entity;
            File f;
            FileBody fb;
            entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            f = new File(zipImageFile);
            fb = new FileBody(f);
            entity.addPart("orderFile", fb);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            Log.e("Uploload Missing Image URL", "" + uri);
            httppost.setEntity(entity.build());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
//              byte[] fileBites=null;
            String line = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

//              fileBites=stringBuffer.toString().getBytes();
//              Log.e("FILE BITES", fileBites+"=>"+fileBites.length);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bObj.reset();
            bObj.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());

            return bObj.toByteArray();

//              return stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString().getBytes();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Response From Server", "" + result);
        writeToFile(result);

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private void writeToFile(byte[] data) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        File file;

        file = new File(AppConstants.DataPath+"/products.zip");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        try {            
        fop.write(data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
    unzipImage(AppConstants.DataPath + "/products.zip",
            AppConstants.DataPath);
}catch (Exception E)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Readers are not meant to read octet streams.

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

You're looking for a [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html).

The `getContent()` method on the `HttpEntity` returns an `InputStream`. Wrap this around a `BufferedInputStream` and write it to a file or a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5 * 1024];
        int numRead = -1;
        while( (numRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer))!= -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        byte[] result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

To save on memory I'd advise you to write to a `BufferedOutputStream` instead of trying to get the bytes from the stream into a data structure. The android device is likely to run out of memory for large zip files.

Comment: I'm not able to combine my code and yours.. :( can you do this for me.?

Comment: All you need to do is construct a `BufferedInputStream` from the entity. I'll leave this as an excercise for you. Just replace your `BufferedReader` with a `BufferedInputStream`. I would recommend against using `ISO-8859-1` like @tianwei suggests in the other answer. An underlying streaming encoder to read binary data is a waste of processing power.

Comment: Ok let me try replacing BufferedReader with a BufferedInputStream as you are saying.. :) and thanks for the reply.

Comment: @DeepakBala I tried this but its not working in my case, I Have done below changes:

BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStreamReader(result1.getEntity().getContent()));

But I am getting below error:

BufferedInputStream cannot be applied to java.io.InputStreamReader

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
private class sendMissingImagesToServer extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        String uri = params[0];
        byte[] data;
        try {

            MultipartEntityBuilder entity;
            File f;
            FileBody fb;
            entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            f = new File(zipImageFile);
            fb = new FileBody(f);
            entity.addPart("orderFile", fb);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            Log.e("Uploload Missing Image URL", "" + uri);
            httppost.setEntity(entity.build());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
            data = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(data);
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString().getBytes();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Response From Server", "" + result);
        writeToFile(result);

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private void writeToFile(byte[] data) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        File file;

        file = new File(AppConstants.DataPath+"/products.zip");
        fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        try {            
        fop.write(data);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
    unzipImage(AppConstants.DataPath + "/products.zip",
            AppConstants.DataPath);
}catch (Exception E)
{

}
}
```

If you covert the bytes to a `String` and then get bytes by `String.getBytes()` ,you need to assume that the encoding must be single-byte like iso-8859-1(not utf-8 nor others).

Change your code from 
`BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));`

to

`BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"ISO-8859-1"));`

And then  `bObj.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());`

to

`bObj.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));`

Comment: I've applied this changes but when trying to unzip it, still getting some error like   "Central Directory Entry not found"

Comment: when I pulled the zip file out the device and tried to unzip on my Windows PC, it is saying "!   C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\products.zip: The archive is corrupt
!   C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\products.zip: The archive is corrupt
!   C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\products.zip: CRC failed in Product_images\UITWEJSDJ.JPG. The file is corrupt
!   C:\Users\Hardik\Desktop\products.zip: The archive is corrupt
"

Comment: Are you sure the whole response´s entity is just the zip´s content?

Comment: yes.. it is working fine in iOS for same response and binary data.. my friend do the same, take the binary data and save it as a zip and extract it. and it is just perfect.

Comment: You can only use the code by saving the InputStream.
And the code is:

public void writeFileViaStream(final File saveFile, final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        if (!saveFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
            saveFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outStream.close();
    }